# Response encoding HTTPconnection get HTML text

Tags: java, post, http-post, httpresponse, httpconnection

I try to read the response (not only this response, but many this from this site) and here is the code of my function:

```
    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendFirstPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://g1.botva.ru/login.php";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "86");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "runscope/0.1");

        String urlParameters = "do_cmd=login&remember=1&password=avmalyutin1234&server=1&email=avmalyutin%40mail.ru";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        System.out.println("Content Type : " + con.getContentType());

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "cp1251"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

        byte [] array = response.toString().getBytes("cp1251");

        String buffff = new String(array);
        System.out.println(buffff);
    }
```

As a Content-type I get **text/html; charset=cp1251** . I try to use encoding cp1251, windows-1251 -- no good results. Once I managed to get an HTML text, but after that, future launches without changing any source code outputs just non-readable symbols. So, how can I get HTML-like text from responce properly?

Answer (score 0):

While the header says that the encoding is `Cp1251`, this is not the reality. The server is sending the bytes corresponding to `Cp1252`.

One way to check is knowing first what bytes are you will receive:

```
String text = "Áîòâà Îíëàéí | Áèòâà çà ðåàëüíóþ êàïóñòó!";

for (byte n : text.getBytes("Cp1251")) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", n);
}
System.out.println();

for (byte n : text.getBytes("Cp1252")) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", n);
}
System.out.println();
```

Then look for them among the bytes that you receive:

```
for(int n; (n = inputStream.read()) > 0; ) {
    System.out.printf("%d ", (byte) n);
}
```